# Jmeter: Avoid rate limiter when making load test. Is there some proxy-rotor or any other way

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Please help me with avoiding rate limiter when making load test.

My case:
I have web resource that I need to perform load testing by Jmeter but it has rate limiter. It means that I can send requests to login from one IP only 100 times per minute(if it will be more that 100 per min, web resource is blocked). I need load web resource 500 time per minute. I need that each request will be from different IP. To make it, I need proxy rotor or something else.

Can you please help me with this question. Probably it can be setup via Jmeter or need third party services for that. If yes, please give example and what service are good with that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your infrastructure capabilities you can

- either go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) by installing 5 JMeter slaves onto 5 different machines
- or add 5 network interfaces or IP aliases to your current machine and configure [JMeter IP spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ip-spoofing-jmeter) so each request would be sent from different IP address coming from i.e. CSV file.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. It should help. What can you say about paid solutions like ProxyMesh or Luminati